# Are these different looks in accordance with the Harry Potter canon?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, sorting-hat

[image: Hermione Granger different looks]

I got this pic from *Movies Now* which says that Hermione would have different makeovers if she belonged to different houses. Is this in accordance with the canon? Does Ravenclaw not have blonde girls? Or, are Slytherin girls more cheekier than others? Is there a similar rule for boys, too? Was Malfoy intentionally made blonde (but, I doubt this after seeing his friends)?

Comment: Y no Hufflepuff?

Comment: @Richard - You *really* need to ask? ;)

Comment: There *is* a Hufflepuff Hermione image floating around; my personal favorite look, in fact, cuz she's a red head. Not sure why the MoviesNow poster didn't include it.

Comment: [The full set of the supposed house variations](http://data1.whicdn.com/images/13905986/original.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No - appearance doesn’t affect what house each student is in.

The Sorting is based on what’s inside the students’ minds, not their appearance.

> *“There’s nothing hidden in your head
>
> The Sorting Hat can’t see,
>
> So try me on and I will tell you
>
> Where you ought to be.”* 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 7 (The Sorting Hat)*</sup></sub>

The Sorting Hat also most likely can’t see the students being Sorted, since he’s on their heads.

## They also don’t represent a “most common” look for each house.

These pictures don’t (at least not in an accurate way) represent the typical or most common appearance of a student from that house. For example, there are actually more known and named Slytherins with dark hair than with blond hair. Draco Malfoy and his parents are the only known and named blond Slytherins, but Severus Snape, Bellatrix, Regulus Black, and the Dark Lord himself were all dark-haired Slytherins. Gryffindors don’t mostly have light brown hair - the Weasleys were all in Gryffindor and all had red hair. There are blonde girls in Ravenclaw - Luna Lovegood was a blond Ravenclaw girl, and Marietta Edgecombe had reddish-blond hair.

## Then, what’s the reasoning behind the different coloring?

Though we can’t know for sure, I do have some theories on the reasons behind the colors of each picture. Gryffindor Hermione looks exactly like normal Hermione since Hermione was actually *in* Gryffindor. The Slytherin Hermione most likely is blond with blue eyes because Draco Malfoy was a very “present” Slytherin in the series, the first Slytherin student most people would think of. Ravenclaw Hermione is most likely dark-haired because Cho Chang is dark haired and the first Ravenclaw student who Harry really paid attention to - and “raven” is often used to describe dark hair. The Hufflepuff Hermione from the same set isn’t shown but has red hair, most likely to distinguish her from the other houses’ Hermiones, since there are four main naturally occurring hair colors possible (other than gray which would be very unlikely for a Hogwarts student).

As for why they’re recolored at all, that may simply be for visual representation. All they’d really need to change to visually indicate the different houses is her house tie, which wouldn’t be a big change visually. Changing the hair colors makes them more noticeably changed from the original, and creates more of a contrast when they’re next to each other.

Answer (score 10):

Nope. The Hogwarts student's Houses are based on the student's personality and choices, not physical appearance. For example, Luna is blonde and is a Ravenclaw, Harry has black hair and is a Griffindor. The Patil twins are sorted into Ravenclaw and Griffindor respectively. Voldemort himself was dark haired and a Slytherin. Lots of other examples, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: Voldemort, the (dark) hair of Slytherin

Comment: @Deltharis That's why he became bald. Looks some kind of magic..

Answer (score 1):

I think they were playing with stereotypes; her hair would have been darker and more brunette to make her seem smarter, and the blonde either to look more stupid/seductive/blend-in.

A Slytherin Hermione would not stop answering questions but she would get smart about it, and I don't think the other pureblood girls in Slytherin would let Hermione ignore her appearance (that would be there soft-side, make overs in the dorm room and giggling about who's cute, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

It's just more of that dreadful stereotyping. (I'm blonde so these stereotypes really get on my nerves.)

Basically: Hermione could have been Gryffindor or Ravenclaw. If she chose Ravenclaw, (the hat took what her choice of values was) she still would have been a light brunette. If Harry was placed in Slytherin, his hair wasn't going to suddenly turn blonde, it would have still had the same color. End of story.